# Why is a DataGridView so row-centric?

Tags: datagridview

Why is there a DataGridViewRow.Cells property, but not a DataGridViewColumn.Cells property?

What's so important about rows that I'll never want to iterate down a column?
I'm not saying that it makes it particularly difficult to do or anything, it just strikes me as oddly asymmetrical.

I'm implementing a "fill down" type behaviour, and it'd be handy is all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say it's simply a side-effect of the fact that relational databases are also row-centric.

Answer (score 2):

In general terms, DataGridView functions to display attributes (as columns) for a list of like entities (as rows). It is not meant to emulate spreadsheet functionality.